# How do i reformat my Macintosh?

Tags: macos, mac, maintenance

How do I **completely** clean out/reset/reformat/whatever my Macintosh?  I'm talking a deep cleanse here.

I'm willing to look at any free software that may aid in this.

I'm running `OSX 10.6.5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot the OS X disc that came with your computer, and in the menu bar, go to `Utilities -> Disk Utility` and select your disk in the left column (e.g. `500GB Hitachi...`). Click on the `Erase` tab at the top, and select `Max OS Extended (Journaled)` from the drop-down menu. Title your disk (if you want, or leave it as *Macintosh HD*), and click `Erase`. Quit disk utility (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>) and continue with the OS X install as normal.

Comment: Then format it as NTFS, then HFS, then FAT32, and you stand a better chance of the data being much harder to retrieve.

Comment: @geoff If you want it harder to retrieve, click `Security Options` beside the `Erase` button and choose one of the three (four?) security options (zero-out data etc.). Guaranteed to be secure. Formatting as different filesystems without zeroing-out data does very little to prevent the data from being readable; it's comparable to changing the cover of a book multiple times: the contents of the book are still intact.

Comment: @geoffc please elaborate. I'd say the little administrative file system data doesn't make much difference. Data won't be erased that way.